# Why I do not need to ensure I have no latches in sequential process [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

As far as I know, it is a bad practice in combination processes to use latches, and that I should assign value to every signal in any case. Why the same rule doesn't stand for sequential processes (by these i mean clock processes) and why I am not warned that for certain signals I don't assign values for?

Comment: Because a clock edge sequential process will have registers - FFs not latches.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Not necessarily, a FF is just two back to back latches with opposite phase clocks.  Most good timing tools (Synopsys Primetime) understand this and will even show this in the timing reports.  And many registers are latches as well for high speed designs.

Answer (score 4):

When we say it's bad practice to infer latches, what we are talking about is *transparent* latches, which are level sensitive, and generally have poor timing performance in an FPGA.

A sequential design infers flip-flops, which are *edge* sensitive on their clock input (and possibly level sensitive on set/reset inputs). Unlike latches, the FPGA is specifically designed to have good performance when implementing sequential designs using flip-flops.

The reason that not assigning an output in certain branches in a sequential process is not harmful, is that doing this will in general infer 'enable' logic for the flip-flop. As a result, its performance is not degraded, as it still operates in an edge sensitive mode, based on the clock.

Latches are not 'bad' *per se*, they are just not the intended design method in an FPGA. There are scenarios where an external interface mandates the use of latches. They are not *always* a mistake, you just need to understand when and where they might be appropriate.

Comment: Spot on apart from it's bad practice to imply latches/FFs. The synthesis tool infers them. I imply, you infer. Very common mistake in English :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will use verilog for the examples in this post because I haven't written any VHDL in years, the principles hold the same for both languages.

First lets consider the non-clocked case

```
always @(en,d) begin
  if (en) begin
    q = d;
  end
end
```

This is a non-clocked always block (the equivilent of a VHDL process). It creates a transparent latch.

The trouble with transparent latches is that they are sensitive to glitches and races.

Consider what happens if en changes to zero at the same time d changes value. You have a race condition. If the change to en arrives first than q gets the old value of d. If the change to d arrives first than q gets the new value of d.

Now consider what happens if the logic creating en is glitchy. A glitch in en may cause the new value of d to be unintentionally propagated to q.

---

Now lets consider the clocked case.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (en) begin
    q <= d;
  end
end
```

Now we no longer get a transparent latch. We get a clocked register. It doesn't matter what order en and d arrive in as long as they arrive in time for the next clock edge. It doesn't matter if there are glitches after one clock edge as long as they have settled down before the next clock edge.